# JMS queue in websphere

Tags: queue, websphere

We are currently using JMS queue in Weblogic. 
Can we use same JMS queue in Websphere as part of weblogic to websphere migration.
Is there any other concept available in websphere which can replace JMS queue?

Answer (score 5):

WebSphere Application Server has a built-in JMS provider, due to the Java EE standard which defines it as mandatory (as Arjan Tijms already stated).
Setting up the JMS provider requires a so called Service Integration Bus, which is a simple Messaging Bus inside WebSphere. The Service Integration Bus also allows to setup High Available JMS queues/topics when using WebSphere Application Server Network Deployment.

Using this queues/topics outside of a WebSphere context - by putting messages into the queues from external clients or reading them from external clients - **is hard**. 
Mainly due to the WebSphere internal CORBA communication it is quite tricky to setup a working and stable
configuration - and you need to know some internal WebSphere tricks.

My recommandation is to use internal jms configuration only for applications which are deployed on the same WebSphere Application Server-Configuration.
If you really need external access to the JMS queues/topics, you should write a adapter to access it.

[This blog post describes in detail how to setup a simple WebSphere internal JMS configuration.](http://www.devops-insight.com/2014/08/jms-in-websphere.html)

Answer (score 2):

WebSphere has indeed an internal JMS provider. It's accessed using the SIB (Service Integration Bus). See http://www.packtpub.com/article/messaging-with-websphere-application-server-7.0-part1

Answer (score 1):

WepSphere has JMS queues as well. Are you wanting to have the queue running within WebSphere, or are you trying to point to a queue running elsewhere?

Answer (score 1):

A JMS provider is mandated by the Java EE specs so every application server has an inbuilt JMS Provider.

You have to make the right calls about your application needs. There might be valid reasons to use an external JMS provider such as WebSphere MQ.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can.

Configuration depends on your JMS System.

If your JMS Middleware is running external like ApacheMQ or Swift JMS, you can normally install an Resource Adapter and then use that specific configuration (at least for the Jms configuration). Then you can use Websphere's JMS Configuration (like Queues and Topics) and therefor your normal MDB configuration.

Besides ActivationSpec (like above) at least with Websphere MQ you could use Listener Ports. I don't know if Listener Ports are available for other JMS Products.

If you want to use a built in Messaging System, you can use SIB I guess.

So plenty of options depending on your System.